# Login facebook with UISwitch button

Tags: ios, facebook, uiswitch

I have used Facebook SDK in application. It requests to use FbLoginView to login in Facebook account. I would like to use `UISwitch` button instead.

- To login in facebook account by tap on `UISwitch` button (not UIButton). How can i do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: if your `UISwitch` is on call the loginviewmethod

Comment: can u show ur uiswitch action method

Comment: Ok thank you Anbu. Karthik , it works fine :)

Comment: done the same action for switch itself.